# Linq Grouping Question

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm working on a simple reservation system for meeting room. Each meeting room is assigned a room type depending on it's size etc. I'm looking to shape the count of booked rooms from the following:

```
01/01/2011  1   Room A  2
01/01/2011  2   Room B  5
01/01/2011  3   Room C  3
01/01/2011  4   Room D  2
01/01/2011  5   Room E  1
01/01/2011  6   Room F  5
02/01/2011  1   Room A  3
02/01/2011  2   Room B  5
02/01/2011  3   Room C  2
02/01/2011  4   Room D  5
02/01/2011  5   Room E  2
02/01/2011  6   Room F  2
03/01/2011  1   Room A  2
03/01/2011  2   Room B  5
03/01/2011  3   Room C  2
```

Into grouped data such as:

```
Date        Room A  Room B  Room C  Room D  Room E  Room F
01/01/2011  2       5       3       2       1       5
02/01/2011  3       5       2       5       2       2
03/01/2011  2       5       2       4       5       8
04/01/2011  4       7       3       5       2       2
```

I've managed to do this previously using Datasets, but I need to be able to do this in Linq for this project using Linq to entites

Can somebody advise the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've done when confronted with this type of problem:

```
var rooms = bookings
    .Select(b => b.Room)
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(r => r)
    .ToArray();

var query = (
    from b in bookings
    group b by b.Date into gbs
    let l = gbs.ToLookup(gb => gb.Room, gb => gb.Count)
    select new
    {
        Date = gbs.Key,
        RoomCounts = rooms.Select(r => l[r].Sum()).ToArray(),
    }).ToArray();
```

This essentially produces the following arrays:

```
var rooms = new []
{
    "Room A", "Room B", "Room C", "Room D", "Room E", "Room F",
};

var query = new []
{
    new
    {
        Date = new DateTime(2011, 01, 01),
        RoomCounts = new [] { 2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 5 }
    },
    new
    {
        Date = new DateTime(2011, 01, 02),
        RoomCounts = new [] { 3, 5, 2, 5, 2, 2 }
    },
    new
    {
        Date = new DateTime(2011, 01, 03),
        RoomCounts = new [] { 2, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0 }
    },
};
```

The `RoomCounts` arrays are all the same length as the `rooms` array and the value at each index position matches the room in the `rooms` array.

It's usually fairly workable.

An alternative is to create an array of arrays that represent a grid somewhat like a spreadsheet.

```
var query2 = (new object[]
    {
        (new object[] { "Date" })
            .Concat(rooms.Cast<object>())
            .ToArray()
    }).Concat(
        from b in bookings
        group b by b.Date into gbs
        let l = gbs.ToLookup(gb => gb.Room, gb => gb.Count)
        select (new object[] { gbs.Key })
            .Concat(rooms.Select(r => l[r].Sum()).Cast<object>())
            .ToArray())
            .ToArray();
```

This produces the following:

```
    var q2 = new object[]
    {
        new object[] {
            "Date", "Room A", "Room B", "Room C", "Room D", "Room E", "Room F" },
        new object[] { new DateTime(2011, 01, 01), 2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 5 },
        new object[] { new DateTime(2011, 01, 02), 3, 5, 2, 5, 2, 2 },
        new object[] { new DateTime(2011, 01, 03), 2, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0 },
    };
```

An alternative to the alternative, in case the query looks a little hairy, is to do this:

```
Func<object, IEnumerable, object[]> prepend = (o, os) =>
    (new object[] { o }).Concat(os.Cast<object>()).ToArray();

Func<object[], IEnumerable<object[]>, object[][]> prepends = (o, os) =>
    (new object[][] { o }).Concat(os).ToArray();

var query2 = prepends(prepend("Date", rooms),
    from b in bookings
    group b by b.Date into gbs
    let l = gbs.ToLookup(gb => gb.Room, gb => gb.Count)
    select prepend(gbs.Key, rooms.Select(r => l[r].Sum())));
```

This form of the query still produces the same grid of objects, but it's a little more readable, IMHO, than the first form.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried these. I'm binding the results to Silverlight Datagrid. Option 1 just displays 7 lines with column for date and roomcounts with no text. Option 2 raises an error at the .Concat(from b in bookings section saying object doesn't contain a definition for concat. Option three looks best, but splits each row into an array so I can't see how I can bind that to the datagrid with the itemsource property? I'm probably missing something obvious?